# Vue 3 ref changes the DOM but reactive doesn't

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

The following code works and I can see the output as intended when use **ref**, but when using **reactive**, I see no changes in the DOM. If I `console.log` **transaction**, the data is there in both cases. Once transaction as a variable changes, should the changes not be reflected on the DOM in both cases?

I'm still trying to wrap my head around Vue 3's composition API and when to use ref and reactive. My understanding was that when dealing with objects, use reactive and use ref for primitive types.

**Using ref it works:**

```
<template>
   {{ transaction }}
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

let transaction = ref({})

const getPayByLinkTransaction = () => {
   axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "pay-by-link",
      params: {
         merchantUuid: import.meta.env.VITE_MERCHANT_UUID,
         uuid: route.params.uuid,
      },
   })
      .then((res) => {
         transaction.value = res.data
      })
      .catch((e) => {
         console.log(e)
      })
}

getPayByLinkTransaction()
</script>
```

**Using reactive it doesn't work:**

```
<template>
   {{ transaction }}
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'

let transaction = reactive({})

const getPayByLinkTransaction = () => {
   axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "pay-by-link",
      params: {
         merchantUuid: import.meta.env.VITE_MERCHANT_UUID,
         uuid: route.params.uuid,
      },
   })
      .then((res) => {
         transaction = { ...res.data }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
         console.log(e)
      })
}

getPayByLinkTransaction()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, when you do `transaction = { ...res.data }` on the reactive object, you override it, like you would with any other variable reference.

What does work is assigning to the reactive object:

```
Object.assign(transaction, res.data)
```

Internally, the object is a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) which uses abstract getters and setters to trigger change events and map to the associated values. The setter can handle adding new properties.

A `ref()` on the other hand is not a Proxy, but it does the same thing with its `.value` getter and setter.

From what I understand, the idea of `reactive()` is not to make any individual object reactive, but rather to collect all your refs in one single reactive object (somewhat similar to the `props` object), while `ref()` is used for individual variables. In your case, that would mean to declare it as:

```
const refs = reactive({transaction: {}})
refs.transaction = { ...res.data }
```

The general recommendation seems to be to pick one and stick with it, and most people seem to prefer `ref()`. Ultimately it comes down to if you prefer the annoyance of having to write `transaction.value` in your script or always writing `refs.transaction` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

With `transaction = { ...res.data }` the variable `transaction` gets replaced with a new Object and loses reactivity.

You can omit it by changing the `data` sub-property directly or by using `ref()` instead of `reactivity()`

This works:

```
let transaction = ref({})
transaction.data = res.data;
```

Check the [Reactivity in Depth](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html) and this great article on Medium [Ref() vs Reactive() in Vue 3](https://medium.com/@bsalwiczek/ref-vs-reactive-in-vue-3-whats-the-right-choice-7c6f7265ce39) to understand the details.

### Playground

```js
const { createApp, ref, reactive } = Vue;

const App = {
  setup() {
    const transaction1 = ref({});
    let transaction2 = reactive({ data: {} });
    const res = { data: { test: 'My Test Data'} };
    const replace1 = () => {            
        transaction1.value = res.data;
    }
    const replace2 = () => {            
        transaction2.data = res.data;
    }
    const replace3 = () => {            
        transaction2.data = {};
    }
    return {transaction1, transaction2, replace1, replace2, replace3 }
  }
}
const app = Vue.createApp(App);
app.mount('#app');
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  transaction1: {{ transaction1 }} &nbsp;
  <button type="button" @click="replace1()">1</button>&nbsp;
  <br/>
  transaction2: {{ transaction2 }} &nbsp;
  <button type="button" @click="replace2()">2</button>&nbsp;
  <button type="button" @click="replace3()">3</button>&nbsp;
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since reactive transaction is an object try to use `Object.assign` method as follows :

```js
 Object.assign(transaction, res.data)
```